# Kinetic energy and conservative fields

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

If $W = E_1 - E_0$ for every force and a conservative field is a field such that the work on a closed path is 0, then every field should be conservative, since $W = E_0 - E_0 = 0$.

I know that this can't be true, but i can't see why

Comment: What do your subscripts represent here? Just positions in space?

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified the meaning of $E_0$ and $E_1$. Are these potential energies in two points in space? Kinetic energies? Total energies?

Comment: They are kinetic energy

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $F$ is a resultant force acting on a system, and $A$ is a work associated with that force, then (Work-Energy Theorem)
$$
A = K_2 - K_1
$$
where K is a kinetic energy of the system. If there are conservative forces we can rewrite the equation simply as 
$$
A_{cons} + A_{other} = K_2 - K_1.
$$
The potential energy $П$ is defined, so that 
$$
A_{cons} = П_1 - П_2, 
$$
hence the work of non-conservative forces is equal to difference in full energy:
$$
A_{other} = (K_2 + П_2) - (K_1 + П_1) 
$$
This equation applied to the closed path will give

$$
A_{other} = K_2 - K_1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your notation presupposes that "the energy at point 0" or "the energy at point 1" is well-defined.  If the work required to move an object from point 0 to point 1 is dependent on the path taken, then we can't meaningfully define a "change in energy" between the two points;  we would also need to know the path taken between the two points.  Only if the work required is path-independent can we even *define* the notion of an object's energy "at a given point".

For example, imagine pushing a box across a table from point 0 to point 1.  The force of friction during this process is constant and opposes the motion;  so the work done is proportional to the distance travelled.  But this means that the work done by friction between these two points depends on how you move the box between these two points.  The quantity "$E_1 - E_0$" doesn't just depend on the positions of the points 0 and 1, and so it's not a very useful thing to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

KE is not a state function, when the system returns to its initial state then KE energy is not necessarily same.Hence work can not be always zero.

Comment: If the KE is different, then the state has not returned to the initial state.